# Android ListView Problems Loading App

Tags: java, listview, android-listview

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    String[] myHouses = new String[8];
    myHouses[0] = "Hello0";
    myHouses[1] = "Hello1";
    myHouses[2] = "Hello2";
    myHouses[3] = "Hello3";
    myHouses[4] = "Hello4";
    myHouses[5] = "Hello5";
    myHouses[6] = "Hello6";
    myHouses[7] = "Hello7";
    ArrayList<String> myHousesList =new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myHouses));

    ListAdapter grumpyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myHousesList);
    ListView grumpyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.grumpyListView);
    grumpyListView.setAdapter(grumpyAdapter);

    grumpyListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String myHouse = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, myHouse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );

}
```

}

Moved my error to this line: null pointer exception again:
ListView grumpyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.grumpyListView);

Comment: New code same problem:

Comment: Can you provide the error from LogCat

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: String[] myHouses = new String[8];
        myHouses[0] = "Hello0";
        myHouses[1] = "Hello1";
        myHouses[2] = "Hello2";
        myHouses[3] = "Hello3";
        myHouses[4] = "Hello4";
        myHouses[5] = "Hello5";
        myHouses[6] = "Hello6";
        myHouses[7] = "Hello7";  will this work as the array?

Comment: Array adapter need ArrayList so you have to add one more line ArrayList<String> myHousesList =new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myHouses)); and then in array adapter parameter instead of sending myHouses use myHousesList

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, there is something wrong with your layout, it can't be inflated, check the corresponding xml layout file.

Comment: Now I'm Here: completely different code lol.java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: ListAdapter grumpyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myHouses);
        ListView grumpyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.grumpyListView);
        grumpyListView.setAdapter(grumpyAdapter);

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an ListAdapter try ArrayAdapter

```
ArrayList<String> myHousesList=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myHouses));
ArrayAdapter<String> grumpyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myHousesList);
 ListView grumpyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.grumpyListView);  
   grumpyListView.setAdapter(grumpyAdapter);
```

Try this